# Polymorphism errors in Scala

Tags: scala

Sorry if this is a real basic question, am relatively new to scala

I am trying to make 2 class which are Disease and Cancer where Cancer class extends the Disease class

```
class Disease ( diseaseNameS : String, symptomsS : String, recommendMedS : String ){
  var diseaseName      = new StringProperty(diseaseNameS)
  var symptoms         = new StringProperty(symptomsS)
  var recommendMed     = new StringProperty(recommendMedS)
}

class Cancer ( diseaseNameS : String, symptomsS : String, recommendMedS : String ) extends Disease (diseaseNameS, symptomsS, recommendMedS){
  override var recommendMedS : String = "Chemotherapy"
}

object Disease {
  val diseaseData = new ObservableBuffer[Disease]()

  diseaseData += new Disease("Common cold", "Headache, Sore throat, Stuffy nose","Decongestants, Ibuprofen")
  diseaseData += new Cancer("Prostate cancer", "Frequent urination", "Radical prostatectomy")

error:
Disease.scala:13:16: recommendMedS is already defined as value recommendMedS
[error]   override var recommendMedS : String = "Chemotherapy"
```

What I want is when I print the diseaseData the "Radical prostatectomy" string in new Cancer will get overrided by "Chemotherapy". Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: That is not the error given by that code. The error is "variable recommendMedS overrides nothing" which is clearly true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution to this specific problem is this:

```
class Cancer(diseaseNameS: String, symptomsS: String)
  extends Disease(diseaseNameS, symptomsS, "Chemotherapy") {
}
```

This prevents someone from specifying a `recommendedMed` for `Cancer` because it is always "Chemotherapy".

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is this:

```
class Cancer(diseaseNameS: String, symptomsS: String, recommendMedS : String = "Chemotherapy")
  extends Disease(diseaseNameS, symptomsS, recommendMedS) {
}
```

This way you don't need to set `recommendMedS` for `Cancer`, and default "Chemotherapy" is used, but if you do set it, the set value is used.